# What is the difference between 'property', '_property', 'self.property' and 'self._property' with read-write and readonly properties?

Tags: objective-c, variables, properties, initialization

I would like to understand it very well, but so far I didn't find complex answer considering all possibilities in one place. I know that in modern objective-c we don't create ivars just after `@implementation Album` between `{ }`.

Just for tests I created **Album.h**:

```
@interface Album : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, copy, readonly) NSString *title, *artist;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title2, *artist2;

- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString*)title;

@end
```

And **Album.m**:

```
@implementation Album

- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString*)title {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {

        //READ-ONLY
        title = title; //1, still nil after compile
        _title = title; //2,
        self.title = title; //3, "assignment to readonly property"
        self._title = title; //4, "property '_title' not found"

        artist = @"Shakira"; //5, "use of undeclared identifier 'artist'"
        _artist = @"Shakira"; //6
        self.artist = @"Shakira"; //7, "assignment to readonly property"
        self._artist = @"Shakira"; //8, "property '_artist' not found"

        //READ-WRITE
        title2 = title; //9, "use of undeclared identifier 'title2'"
        _title2 = title; //10
        self.title2 = title; //11
        self._title2 = title; //12, "property '_title2' not found"

        artist2 = @"Shakira"; //13, "use of undeclared identifier 'artist2'"
        _artist2 = @"Shakira"; //14
        self.artist2 = @"Shakira"; //15
        self._artist2 = @"Shakira"; //16, "property '_artist2' not found"

    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Now I use it:

```
Album *album = [[Album alloc] initWithTitle:@"Live from Paris"];
```

The questions are:

1. Why 4, 8, 12, 16 properties not found while 2, 6, 10, 14 exists?
2. What is the difference between 10 and 11 or 14 and 15?
3. What I actually do in 1?
4. Where did I declare properties 2, 6, 10, 14?
5. Why I can assign to readonly properties in 2, 6 but not in 3, 7?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some explanations at the beginning

A. `@property` *declares* *methods* with the name `-property` and, if it is not read only, `-setProperty:`. Nothing else is done by `@property` itself!

B. `@property` does *not* synthesize an ivar. What? Say it again! `@property` does *not* synthesize an ivar. (I can repeat that as many times as you want.)

Ivars are synthesized, when you use an explicit `@synthesize` or – and that makes it a little bit difficult to understand – when you have auto synthesize. But there is still an (implicit, unshown) synthesize!

To have an implicit synthesize, the following conditions have to be met:

- You need an @property.
- You do *not* implement the accessors manually.

Since you can see the first condition in source code and cannot see the second condition, it is easy to assume that `@property` synthesized the ivar. But it is not true. Let's try it:

```
@interface Foo : NSObject
@property NSString *foo;
@end

@implementation Foo
// Both accessors are implemented -> no auto synthesize -> no ivar
- (NSString*)foo
{
  return _foo; // Error: No ivar _foo
}

- (NSString*)setFoo:(NSString*)foo
{
  _foo=foo; // Error: No ivar _foo
}
@end
```

The reason is: If `@property` itself would synthesize the ivar, it would be impossible to have a declared property that is not backed with an ivar.

(Additionally no ivar is synthesized, if you already have one that fits. But we do not need that here.)

C. An synthesized ivar has the identifier `_property`, not `property`. (In some cases a existing ivar without underscore would be taken as an already existing ivar, but we do need that here, too.)

D. The dot notation does *not* access an ivar. It sends a message. If the statement is an lvalue, is uses the setter, if it is a rvalue, it uses the getter. You can simply translate that:

```
self.property = …; // [self setProperty:…];
… = self.property; // … = [self property];
```

> Why 4, 8, 12, 16 properties not found while 2, 6, 10, 14 exists?

At 4, … you use dot notation, send a message with the selector `set_Property`. There is no such method, because the synthesized method is `-setProperty:`: Error

At 2, … you access the ivars directly. It's identifier is `_property`. Everything is fine.

> What is the difference between 10 and 11 or 14 and 15?

At 11, 15 you set the value of the property using a setter. At 10, 14 you set the ivar directly. The code of the setter is not executed.

Let's have an example:

```
@interface Foo : NSObject
@property NSString *foo;
@end

@implementation Foo
// ivar _foo is (auto) synthsized, because there is no getter.
- (void)setFoo:(NSString*)foo
{
  NSLog( @"Setter executed");
  _foo = foo;
}
@end
```

In line 10, 14 you will see no log, because the setter is not executed. In line 11, 15 you will see a log.

If you have additional things to do in the setter (or getter) accept of only setting the ivar, the result will differ.

> What I actually do in 1?

`title`is not an ivar (the identifier of the ivar is `_title`), but a parameter var. (Look at the head of the method definition.) You assign the value of the parameter var to itself, what is a kind of meaningless.

You assign nothing to the ivar, because you do not use the ivar.

> Where did I declare properties 2, 6, 10, 14?

See above A. and B.

> Why I can assign to readonly properties in 2, 6 but not in 3, 7?

The ivar is never read only. The `readonly` and `readwrite` options are for the method declaration. (See above A. - C.)

In 2, 6 you set the ivar directly. It cannot be read only, so everything is pretty fine.

In 3, 7 you send a message to a method that does not exists, because the *property* is read only.

Comment: `What is the difference between 10 and 11 or 14 and 15?` Your answer shouldn't be conversely? A few lines before you said that `_property` is assign it directly...

Comment: So it is not possible to get to the property directly: `title2 = @"value"`, only by accessors or its iVar?

Comment: So I do not set up iVars, but they are created at which moment of my code if `@property` doesn't create them?

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk I told you the difference?! Of course it is possible. 10, 11 and 14, 15 are both valid, but do different things as mentioned in my answer.

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk I added an example for that question.

Comment: I mean, that you said "At 11, 15 you set the ivar directly.". Are You sure?

Comment: Ah, it is exactly vice versa. I change that.

Answer (score 4):

when you type

```
self.title = @"foo";
```

it is    really shorthand for

```
[self setTitle:@"foo" ];
```

You don't implement

```
-(void)setTitle:(NSString *)title
```

the compiler has synthesised it for you. If you could see what it has put there it might look something like this

```
-(void)setTitle:(NSString *)title{
_title = [title copy];
}
```

So you see _title is an instance variable.  title is not, it is a method which returns an NSString.  It has been synthesised for you, but it looks like this

```
-(NSString *)title{
return _title;
}
```

They are fundamentally different things.  If title is readonly then the setTitle: method is never synthesised, although the _title iVar is still there.  So when you type self.title = @"bar" the compiler looks for -(void)setTitle .. which is not there. -> unhappy compiler

The best practice is to avoid using the _underScore variables (known as backing iVars) directly.  Always use self.title = @"some
Title" instead.  If you ever want to use key value observing, which is one of cocoas best features, you'll be glad you did.

Comment: So, conclusion: for readwrite properties always use: `self.title = @"value"`, but what about readonly properties? when I type `self.title = @"value"` i got an error.

Comment: yes well for a readonly property you do have that _title iVar there to set directly if you wish.  Often in practice readonly properties will not even have a backing iVar, they might be computed in the getter. for example a rectangle might have readwrite properties for width and height, but a readonly property of area.  We don't keep a variable for this, which would be a pain in the neck to update with each setWidth or setHeight.  Instead we just implement area for ourselves -(CGFloat )area{ return self.width*self.height;  }

Comment: At any rate KVO is unlikely to be much of an issue with a readonly property, why bother watching something that you won't allow anybody to change :)

Comment: `-(CGFloat )area{ return self.width*self.height; } ` - this is an example of readonly property only with getter, when `get {}` inside is optional. Am I right? In this case we do not have to assign an initial value for readonly property, because this property is computed.

Comment: right, so no bit of memory is required to store anything.  That was just a real quick example that we'd all understand, this might be a more complex computation that only our class knows how to do, based on its other data members